# How to make multiple versions of the same record, with F#

Tags: f#

I have 3 state machines that follow the similar model:

```
- same states
- same calls for each state
```

only the implementation of these calls change.
All the data is carried in a single record that also contains a DU that has the state and there are also a few other common parameters. Each implementation also adds their own fields to that record.

So I would like to figure out if there is a way to make a record I can extend but that contains a number of common fields that the code is expecting to find. Something similar to an interface for a type, but for a record.

For example:

```
type State =
    | a
    | b


type StateMachine1StateObject =
    {
         State: State
         SomeData: ...
    }

type StateMachine2StateObject =
    {
         State: State
         SomeOtherKindOfData: ...
    }
```

and I would like to have a single state machine loop (which is really a mailbox processor loop) take all the same messages, and be able to rely on some fields that will always be there in that type, but the records themselves may be different as they contain their own fields.

How can this be structured? It looks like I can't use interfaces with records nor combine multiple records into one.

Comment: the easiest way for mailboxprocessor is to have the inside of the loop and not as part of the message. Perhaps make the message (State * Msg) where Msg = | SomeData of data | SomeOtherKindOfData of data2

Comment: Yes I could do state*customRecord but the functions called work on both so I was hoping there would be some elegant mechanism I haven’t discovered yet :)

Comment: I have a feeling you are looking for ways to simplify, but instead end up over-engineering. If you have three state machines, then consider coding them separately. If you have states with some fields in common, then the best option may be to just repeat those fields.

Comment: They are already separated but as things iterate most of the code ends up being the same and now I have three pieces of code to maintain / update when there is a change (which is happening regularly since the whole system is being developed / tested at the same time). The more I can lower duplication the better in this scenario

Comment: I think we need some more code to understand fully

Comment: I can build some pseudo code, but the real code is quite large with a lot of states and records having 50+ fields

Comment: What do the state machines do? I suspect you can extract the logic related to what the state machine is doing from the specific operations assocaited with individual state machines somehow. That way, you could have one reusable state machine and parameterize it to do the different specific tasks.

Comment: The records keep track of open positions and active orders on a financial exchange. And the states start from a basic set (setup, waiting for events, various kind of aborts and errors, etc) but the state machine has a lot of combinations (when message x while in state y). This repeats across the 3 state machines and only the implementations of the actions carried change (can be handled with an abstract type) as well as the type of extra data in the record (since it's a common set + some fields specific to one of the 3 systems). There is a lot shared.

Comment: the code passes around the record as it contains everything: every message received calls some code that gets the record as a parameter and returns a message along with the updated record. What I struggle with is to make that code generic since part of the record is common to all implementations, and this is the part the state machine sees. Essentially I'm looking for some elegant way to implement the equivalent of an interface on a record so for the state machine all records look the same type, but for the functions called they're specific.

Comment: A shallow class hierarchy can possibly be simpler than a combination of records and interfaces. I've done this, and it worked well. Somebody might scream at me now, but I favor pragmatism over purism to reach for simplicity, and I believe F# supports me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data in common then can create for example a record, with a field, that has a generic type.

```
type State<'a> = {
    Name:     string
    Id:       int
    Extended: 'a
}

type Person = {
    FirstName: string
    LastName:  string
}

type Computer = {
    CPU: string
    Ghz: float
}
```

This way, you can create a state that have different Extended data

```
// State<Person>
let x = {
    Name = "foo"
    Id   = 1
    Extended = {
        FirstName = "David"
        LastName  = "Raab"
    }
}

// State<Computer>
let y = {
    Name = "bar"
    Id   = 2
    Extended = {
        CPU = "AMD"
        Ghz = 3.6
    }
}
```

You also could convert from one record to another. Your state machine, only accepts a record with those data it needs. For exmaple, you have a state machine that only needs `Name` and `Id`. You create.

```
type StateA = {
    Name: string
    Id:   int
}
```

Assume you now have a different state with shared keys.

```
type StateB = {
    Name:  string
    Id:    int
    Extra: float
}
```

Instead of type hackery, generics and so on, the easiest way is just to convert from B to A.

```
let stateBtoA (record:StateB) : StateA = {
    Name = record.Name
    Id   = record.Id
}
```

So your state machine only accepts `StateA`, and you have a bunch of function, and other types must be converted to `StateA` before passing it to the state machine.

If for some reason your state machine, needs access to the orignal data, you should be able to pass it as a generic paramter to a function call. Like

```
    message (x:StateA) (y:'a) : 'a =
       // do something with x
       y

    message (stateBtoA data) data
```

So your function could work on the first argument, that is of `StateA`, and for example returns the second argument `y` that could be `StateB`. As long your function does nothing with `y`. It should be generic.